# Google Identity Platform, unable to enable

Tags: google-identity

I have attempted to enable Identity Platform for my Google App Engine project. I get the message:

```
We are unable to enable identity platform on your project... Try again later
```

Subsequent attempts also product the message:

```
Page not viewable for organizations. To view this page, select a project.
```

Repeated attempts to enable Identity Platform produce the same result. What causes this and what steps are necessary to resolve it?

Following the instruction, and selecting the project does not clear the problem.

Billing is enabled for the project and it has been running without problem for a few years.

Comment: Are you upgrading to `Identity Platform` from a `firebase` project or a Google Identity Toolkit project?

Comment: I am migrating a Google Identity Toolkit project.  I have migrated from appengine project to an organization based on the hypothesis that it was resource management or permission issue (it was formerly a "no organization" project). Still no luck enabling the Identity Platform.

Comment: I contacted Google via paid support account. Their reply was that Identity Platform is broken and the product team is aware of the issue. No ETA on a fix, but I've been told I'll get an update in 24 hours. I'll add a comment with news, for the benefit of lurkers who may be experiencing the same problems, when I have news. Uhgg... Google... I feel let me down, you're shutting down Identity Toolkit and the replacement is broken with no ETA for a fix.

Comment: Update: I asked Google paid support if there were plans to extend the Identity Toolkit shutdown date in light of the Identity Platform problems. They have no information. They suggested I tried enabling IdentityPlatform on another project, so I did, using a separate account that I keep for development testing, and the same problem occurred.  So a paid app, paid support, shutting down legacy service, broken replacement, on hold with no path forward. Cringe.

Comment: Identity Platform is broken, or at least enabling it is broken, and there is no ETA on fixing it. That's the latest from Google.

Comment: I recommend you just migrate to Firebase. You should be able to migrate from Google Identity Toolkit to Firebase without any issue. This way you don't have to worry about getting shut down until the issue is fixed.

Comment: @bojeil Yes, thanks. That's what Google support suggested (... $100 in support fees not well spent). I'm investigating Firebase Auth now. I burned a good amount of time simply because I read the docs carefully, considered which of the two options to pursue, and selected the one that is broken. Frustrating, but at least there is a path.

Comment: Final update: I migrated my application to Firebase Auth without issue, no data loss or user account interruption. All the Identity Toolkit accounts magically appeared in Firebase. Job with that Google. Google support left me with the impression that Identity Platform will be fixed, but without an ETA, in case anyone is keeping track.  Thanks @bojeil for your feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the update @jptknta.